# sed replace token in a multiline file with the contents of another file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, sed

File 1:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="REPLACE_ME"></head><body></body></html>
```

File 2:

```
<meta name="A" content="A1"><meta name="B" content="B1">
```

I am trying to replace the `<meta name="REPLACE_ME">` in `File 1` with the entire contents of `File 2`.

Expected result:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="A" content="A1"><meta name="B" content="B1"></head><body></body></html>
```

If `File 1` had multiple lines I have this working with something like this:

```
TOKEN="<meta name=\\\"REPLACE_ME\\\">"
sed -e "/${TOKEN}/r file2" -e "/${TOKEN}/d" file1
```

The issue I am having is figuring out how to do this with `sed` when things are **NOT on separate lines** in `File 1`.

Have this as my last attempt:

```
TOKEN="<meta name=\\\"REPLACE_ME\\\">"
sed "s/${TOKEN}/$(sed -e 's/[\&/]/\\&/g' -e 's/$/\\n/' file2 | tr -d '\n')/" file1
```

However, is funky and uses `tr` which I would like to avoid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't parse/modify XML/HTML using line-oriented tools. Better change the examples to plain, unstructured text to evade downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, you should use a dedicated html parser for this but with your limited sample data, it is possible to achieve what you need with sed:

```
sed -zrn 's@\n@@g;s@(^.*<head>)('"$TOKEN"')(</head>.*</html>)(<meta.*$)@\1\4\3@p' <(cat file1 file2)
```

Redirect a single input stream into sed and consume as one line with (-z) First remove any newlines and then split the line into 4 section described in parenthesis using regular expressions (-r or -E) and utilising the variable TOKEN. Replace the line for sections 1 followed by 4 and 3.

I know there should be no need to use cat to direct as one stream as sed should see the files as one stream unless -s is used but I was having trouble when splitting the line.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(.*)<meta name="REPLACE_ME">(.*)/echo "\1$(cat file2)\2"/e' file1
```

Match on `<meta name="REPLACE_ME">` and use back references to collect the data either side of the match. Then evaluate and echo a string composed of the back references and file2 sandwiched between them.